# Accessing Samba shared file from URL

Tags: url, digital-ocean, samba

I have created a `samba shared file` on DigitalOcean droplet Ubuntu and it works fine, I can access this shared file from my Windows.

As I am working on the web application that has users, and a users profile picture is stored in DB as a url to his picture. So I need a url to access the picture(stored in samba shared file).

After doing some research, I have tested different options:

```
smb://username:pass@hostname/shared_files 

smb://DOMAIN;username:pass@hostname/shared_files
```

where `hostname` is my virtual machine adress

But had no luck. I am new to this, so I would like to know
if it is possible to access `samba shared files` from URL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, after doing some research, this question does not have an answer. Samba is not used for that.